# Python - recursive string lookup

Tags: python

I am trying to parse a cisco config firewall output. I am trying to recursive lookup to nested `object-group` until I find the IP of each `object-group`

This is a scenario example:

```
asa# sh object-group id aws_all_critical_vpcs
object-group network aws_all_critical_vpcs
 group-object aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_app_db
 group-object aws_critical_us_west_2_app_db
 group-object aws_criticalprd_us_east_1_app_db
 group-object aws_critical_us_east_1_app_db
 group-object aws_criticalprd_eu_west_1_app_db
 group-object aws_critical_eu_west_1_app_db
 group-object aws_criticalprd_eu_central_1_app_db
 group-object aws_critical_eu_central_1_app_db

asa# sh object-group id aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_app_db
object-group network aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_app_db
 group-object aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_app
 group-object aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_db

asa# sh object-group id aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_app
object-group network aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_app
 network-object 10.159.160.0 255.255.248.0

asa#  sh object-group id aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_db
object-group network aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_db
 network-object 10.159.168.0 255.255.248.0
```

I have managed to have something working but there is a limitation of nested level that the code can dig out due to hardcoded `if/else`

```
    for e in og_content:
        if 'group-object' not in e:
            new_og_content.append(e)
        elif 'group-object' in e:
            new_og_content.append(e)
            for k in find_the_lines(og_list,e.split()[1]):
                new_og_content.append(k)
                if 'network-object' in k:
                    new_og_content.append(' ' + k)
                elif 'group-object' in k:
                    for z in find_the_lines(og_list,k.split()[1]):
                        if 'network-object' in z:
                            new_og_content.append(' ' + z)
```

the output looks good and it is as I want but I would like to have something smarter that does not have limitation in number of lookup for nested object-groups. Here an output example:

```
group-object aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_app_db
 group-object aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_app
  network-object 10.159.160.0 255.255.248.0
 group-object aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_db
  network-object 10.159.168.0 255.255.248.0
group-object aws_critical_us_west_2_app_db
 group-object aws_critical_us_west_2_app
  network-object 10.159.192.0 255.255.248.0
 group-object aws_critical_us_west_2_db

 ...etc...
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: are lead groups always separated by a blank newline and the subsections have no newlines inside them?

Comment: Instead of writing all levels of `if/else` I guess you could write a function that checks the level and if there is another level, feed it to itself. So a recursive function.

Comment: @modesitt No they are not but i can easily make it happen adding `\n`every time `object-group` is found.The children lines always have 1 white space at the begin though. That is an extract of a broader output

Answer (score 0):

TTP can help to parse this data and transform it using python function, here is sample code:

```
from ttp import ttp

template = """
<input load="text">
asa# sh object-group id aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_app
object-group network aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_app
 network-object 10.159.160.0 255.255.248.0
 network-object 10.159.161.0 255.255.248.0
asa#  sh object-group id aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_db
object-group network aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_db
 network-object 10.159.168.0 255.255.248.0

asa# sh object-group id aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_app_db
object-group network aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_app_db
 group-object aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_app
 group-object aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_db

asa# sh object-group id aws_all_critical_vpcs
object-group network aws_all_critical_vpcs
 group-object aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_app_db
 group-object aws_critical_us_west_2_app_db
 group-object aws_criticalprd_us_east_1_app_db
 group-object aws_critical_us_east_1_app_db
 group-object aws_criticalprd_eu_west_1_app_db
 group-object aws_critical_eu_west_1_app_db
 group-object aws_criticalprd_eu_central_1_app_db
 group-object aws_critical_eu_central_1_app_db
</input>

<group name="{{ network_obj }}">
object-group network {{ network_obj }}
 group-object {{ group_obj | to_list | joinmatches }}
 network-object {{ subnet | PHRASE | to_list | joinmatches }}
</group>

<macro>
def lookup_objects(data, name=""):
    # kick recursion off
    if name == "":
        return {key: lookup_objects(data, name=key) for key in data[0].keys()}
    # if name in data, check if it contains subnet or run recursion for group_obj:
    elif name in data[0]:
        if "subnet" in data[0][name]:
            return data[0][name]["subnet"]
        return {
            group_obj: lookup_objects(data, name=group_obj) 
            for group_obj in data[0][name].get("group_obj", [])
        }
    else:
        return {}
</macro>

<output macro="lookup_objects"/>
"""

parser = ttp(template=template)
parser.parse()
print(parser.result(format="json")[0])
```

output would be:

```
{
    "aws_all_critical_vpcs": {
        "aws_critical_eu_central_1_app_db": {},
        "aws_critical_eu_west_1_app_db": {},
        "aws_critical_us_east_1_app_db": {},
        "aws_critical_us_west_2_app_db": {},
        "aws_criticalprd_eu_central_1_app_db": {},
        "aws_criticalprd_eu_west_1_app_db": {},
        "aws_criticalprd_us_east_1_app_db": {},
        "aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_app_db": {
            "aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_app": [
                "10.159.160.0 255.255.248.0",
                "10.159.161.0 255.255.248.0"
            ],
            "aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_db": [
                "10.159.168.0 255.255.248.0"
            ]
        }
    },
    "aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_app": [
        "10.159.160.0 255.255.248.0",
        "10.159.161.0 255.255.248.0"
    ],
    "aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_app_db": {
        "aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_app": [
            "10.159.160.0 255.255.248.0",
            "10.159.161.0 255.255.248.0"
        ],
        "aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_db": [
            "10.159.168.0 255.255.248.0"
        ]
    },
    "aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_db": [
        "10.159.168.0 255.255.248.0"
    ]
}
```

**How it works**

TTP runs parsing using group defined, this group itself would produce this output:

```
[
    {
        "aws_all_critical_vpcs": {
            "group_obj": [
                "aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_app_db",
                "aws_critical_us_west_2_app_db",
                "aws_criticalprd_us_east_1_app_db",
                "aws_critical_us_east_1_app_db",
                "aws_criticalprd_eu_west_1_app_db",
                "aws_critical_eu_west_1_app_db",
                "aws_criticalprd_eu_central_1_app_db",
                "aws_critical_eu_central_1_app_db"
            ]
        },
        "aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_app": {
            "subnet": [
                "10.159.160.0 255.255.248.0",
                "10.159.161.0 255.255.248.0"
            ]
        },
        "aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_app_db": {
            "group_obj": [
                "aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_app",
                "aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_db"
            ]
        },
        "aws_criticalprd_us_west_2_db": {
            "subnet": [
                "10.159.168.0 255.255.248.0"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

above structure processed further using "lookup_objects" function defined within macro tag, this function recursively looks up for "group_obj" names substituting them with values from above results.

If you want to run above template, TTP need to be installed from github repository, not from pypi, e.g. clone source code from [repo](https://github.com/dmulyalin/ttp), unzip and run "python setup.py install"